# RegEx pattern not working: Matching everything after the last part of a domain name in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to match everything after a specific part of an url, and I cannot get this regEx to work:

```
$url = 'http://mywebsite.online/noticia/mi-noticia-copada';
$regexPattern =  '/^online(.*?)/';
preg_match($regexPattern, $eliminar, $matches);
```

I get an empty array in $matches.

I have this string:

> http://mywebsite.online/noticia/mi-noticia-copada

And I want to get ths:

> noticia/mi-noticia-copada

I have this other example string:

> http://mywebsite.online/mi-otra-noticia-copada

And I want to get ths:

> mi-otra-noticia-copada

So far the examples that I've read about won't work.

Comment: Why not use what already exists … https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you've anchored your regex to the start of string by using `^`, so it will only match strings that start with `online`. You can change your regex to match `.online` as the end of the domain name instead:

```
$url = 'http://mywebsite.online/noticia/mi-noticia-copada';
$regexPattern =  '#^https?://[^/]+\.online/(.*)$#';
preg_match($regexPattern, $url, $matches);
echo $matches[1] . PHP_EOL;

$url = 'http://mywebsite.online/mi-otra-noticia-copada';
preg_match($regexPattern, $url, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Output:

```
noticia/mi-noticia-copada
mi-otra-noticia-copada
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2C2Ia)

Answer (score 1):

This expression might return the desired output:

```
^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:[\w]+\.[\w]+)*\/(.*)$
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/71WOBg/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/71WOBg/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### Test

```
$re = '/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:[\w]+\.[\w]+)*\/(.*)$/m';
$str = 'http://mywebsite.online/noticia/mi-noticia-copada
http://mywebsite.online/mi-otra-noticia-copada
http://mywebsite.onlinem.ywebsite.online/noticia/mi-noticia-copada
http://mywebsite.online/mi-otra-noticia-copada
https://www.mywebsite.online/mi-otra-noticia-copada';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```